# How do I mount a WD MyBook World network drive in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, mount, backup

I have a WD MyBook World NAS on my home network.  I currently use this for Time Machine backups for my Mac but I'd also like to use it as a backup location for my linux box which is running Ubuntu Server.  How can I mount this drive on the linux server so that my cron backups can use it as a backup destination?

I have configured the WD drive with a static IP address which I assume would be important in the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/?id=142&type=25), the MyBook supports both the CIFS/SMB and the NFS protocols.

CIFS/SMB is the protocol natively used by Windows for accessing network drives. You should be able to access the MyBook on a Linux/Unix system by using the [smbclient](http://linux.die.net/man/1/smbclient) or [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs), e.g. to access (mount) the "public" folder on MyBook on the local directory `/mnt` you would issue (from a `root` terminal):

```
mount.cifs //ip.address.of.mybook/public /mnt -o username=admin,password=admin_passwd_on_mybook
```

or, equivalently:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=admin,password=... //ip.address.of.mybook/public /mnt
```

where:

1. you can substitute "public" with "download" (to access the pre-defined download share) or any share name that you have created with the MyBook storage manager.
2. username/password can be those of any user that you have created on the MyBook storage manager interface; or just use `-o guest` instead of `-o username=...,password=...` to specify "Guest" access.

Access by the NFS protocol is not enabled by default; you have first to enable it in the "Advanced" tab of the MyBook storage manager, then you can mount the disk shares via NFS with:

mount -t nfs ip.address.of.mybook/nfs/public /mnt

Again, "public" can be any defined share name.

Comment: If you get an ``invalid block device`` error, try ``# aptitude install cifs-utils`` on Debian based distros (such as Ubuntu) and ``# yum install cifs-utils`` on RedHat based ones.

Comment: I got this working in the past, but now starting from scratch with a fresh install. All i get is the 'unknown file systems type -cifs' error?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I had in mind that the WD MyBook World is only accessible by the MioNet software; however, the links may still be helpful:

---

There is good and bad news.

Bad news first: The official statement of the vendor is the following:

> Does MioNet work with Macintosh or
>   Linux computers?
>
> Currently, MioNet
>   works with only Windows-based
>   computers. However, our platform will
>   be extended to these operating systems
>   in the future.

[Mionet FAQ](http://www.mionet.com/products/faqs.aspx#faq_18)

Good News: The WD MyBook World runs a linux system which can be "opened". You can enable ssh and install additional packages:

> The system partition has 2.8GB (only
>   260 MB is occupied). This means that
>   you have a lot of resources for
>   various improvements.

Here are two guides to open the NAS:

[Hacking Western Digital MyBook World Edition](http://martin.hinner.info/mybook/)
[Hacking WD MyBook World Ed](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/)

The chapter ["MyBook World Edition acting as a NFS server"](http://martin.hinner.info/mybook/nfs_server.php) could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 generations of MyBook World. The 'blue rings' version does not have an NFS server installed by default; the 'white lights' version does have an NFS server... it just needs to be enabled in the web interface, so whether you can mount your MyBook World as type NFS or not depends on what version you have (and if you have the 'blue rings' version, whether you have installed the ipkg extender and its NFS server package).